# JS - exibir elementos na tela a partir de um objeto

Tags: javascript, html, array

Preciso montar um questionário na tela com perguntas e alternativas trazidas de um banco de dados, é possível montar a tela com `label` e `radiobuttons` sem colocar um `foreach` no `html`, mas sim utilizando `JavaScript`?

Eu recebo o objeto desta forma:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que seu objeto tem essa estrutura, você pode montar os componentes e incluir em uma `div` usando `innerHTML`:

```js
var obj = {
  "perguntas": [{
    "campanhaId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "pergunta 1",
    "respostas": [
      "alternativa A",
      "alternativa B",
      "alternativa C"
    ]
  }, {
    "campanhaId": 2,
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "pergunta 2",
    "respostas": [
      "alternativa A",
      "alternativa B",
      "alternativa C"
    ]
  }]
};
var div = document.getElementById("perguntas")
  , texto = '';
obj.perguntas.forEach(function(item){
  texto += "<label>" + item.nome + "</label><br/>";
  item.respostas.forEach(function(res){
    texto += "<input type='radio' name='" +item.campanhaId+ "'>" + res + "</input><br/>";
  });
});

div.innerHTML = texto;
```

```html
<div id="perguntas"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lucas, era exatamente isso que queria fazer.